# Should I use .innerText or .value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's a problem I've encountered but can't find explanation so far. The code is as follows:

```js
let textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
let result = document.getElementById("result");

function convertToCm() {
  value = textbox.value;
  result.innerText = +value * 2.54;
  document.body.appendChild(result);
}
```

```html
<input id="textbox" type="text">
<button onclick="convertToCm()">Convert to cm</button>
<div id="result">result</div>
```

In the second line of the function, I tried to use `textbox.innerText` instead, however this gives me output of 0 of whichever number I put in the textbox. In the third line, I also tried to use `result.value` instead, but it would then output the same number I put in the textbox. I'm really confused.

I've tried looking on a search engine but haven't found an explanation so far. What can I try next?

Comment: idk what's going on with the indentation and layout, seems like stack overflow took down my code screenshot link and scanned it automatically and posted the code instead, it's a mess now and I cant reupload or edit the question again

Comment: thank u !! sorry I'm new to this and thought that first comment was from the officials -.-'' thanks for ur help!!!

Answer (score 3):

To get or set value from input field we need to use **.value** as you write `textbox.value` which is correct.

```
<input id="textbox" type="text">
```

---

To get or set value from common elements (it could be any element/tag) we use **.innerText** as you write `result.innerText` which is correct.

```
<div id="result">result</div>
```

---

Also you don't need `document.body.appendChild(result);` line in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Your `textbox` refers to an [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) (or `<input>`), which is a [void element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#void-elements). As such, its `.innerText` is always an empty string.
Converting an empty string to a number will evaluate to zero.

Instead, use [`.value`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#a-form-control%27s-value) to read or write to a form control's value (form controls are for example `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`).

To read or write a non-void element's text, use [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) (or preferably [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), because [reading from it doesn't cause a reflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)). Your variable `result` references an HTMLDivElement—a non-void element.

In the second line you update `result.innerText`. This will be reflected in the DOM immediately.
Because `result` already exists in the DOM, and is updated as you wanted, it is actually unnecessary to reappend it.

**Feedback:**
I recommend to keep functionality purely in your `<script>` (or JS file) for maintainability. [Using the *onevent* HTML attributes is (usually) deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). Instead, use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

- Allows multiple event listeners to be added.
- Allows setting of [`options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#options) for the listener.
- Easier finding of dead code.
- The event object is always passed as the first argument, instead of having to manually pass it or use the deprecated [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) property.
- Doesn't clutter the HTML.

Comment: thank u so much! I finally get it now